# angular-chart.js: How do I use dynamic data from a variable instead of static values for my charts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am using this framework to draw charts with angularjs:http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/. I already searched stackoverflow but no question could really solve my problem.

I have no problem drawing charts with static data, for example $scope.data = [50,30,70]

I want the chart to use the values stored in a variable instead, and I assumed I could simply put my values in an array and do something like $scope.data = myArray; or put my variable in the array like $scpe.data = [myData]; but this doesn't work and I have no clue what else to try. I am new to angularJS and Chart.js btw.

As a test I just wanted to read my cpuload and put it into a chart.

Here is my html:

```
   <div style="width:300px; height:300px" ng-controller="BarCtrl">   
        <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
            chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"> chart-series="series"
        </canvas>
    </div>
```

Here are my angular controllers:

```
app.controller('MonitorController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var vm = this;
setInterval(function(){
    si.currentLoad(function(data) {
    vm.cpuLoad = Math.round(data.currentload); 

    $scope.$apply();

 }); }, 1000);
}])

app.controller("BarCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.labels = ['2017'];
$scope.series = ['Series A'];

$scope.data = [50]; });
```

I want $scope.data to use the value from vm.cpuLoad.

Can anyone help me how to do that? You can also ignore the intervall if you want. Just tell me how to apply the data from a variable in another controller in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a typo in your HTML

Comment: Could you point out what you mean and if that is of relevance to my problem. I just copied the html from the official website.

Comment: The attribute `chart-series="series"` is outside of the `<canvas>` tag